# How can I show a printk() message in a console?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, printk

The information which is printed by printk() can only be seen under the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ~ <kbd>F7</kbd> consoles.

These consoles are very inconvenient for debugging since they can't roll back. I am using the [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Software_Compilation) desktop environment and console terminal. How could I redirect the printk() message to a console?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170403/printk-showing-in-message-log-but-not-in-terminal-for-any-kernel-log-level

Comment: The keys shift+pgup should scroll up.

Comment: Use this command`dmesg -n8`. This would redirect all printk messages to the active console terminal.

Comment: @indiv The scrollback buffer is cleared after switching consoles.

Comment: There are multiple ways of getting the kernel log in the terminal emulator programs depending on the system. dmesg, tail -f /var/log/<log file you are interested in>..

Comment: Re *"roll back"*: Do you mean *"scroll back"*?

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of [printk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printk) is

```
printk ("log level" "message", <arguments>);
```

The kernel defines eight log levels in the header file *printk.h*:

```
#define KERN_EMERG "<0>" /* system is unusable*/
#define KERN_ALERT "<1>" /* action must be taken immediately*/
#define KERN_CRIT "<2>" /* critical conditions*/
#define KERN_ERR "<3>" /* error conditions*/
#define KERN_WARNING "<4>" /* warning conditions*/
#define KERN_NOTICE "<5>" /* normal but significant condition*/
#define KERN_INFO "<6>" /* informational*/
#define KERN_DEBUG "<7>" /* debug-level messages*/
```

Each log level corresponds to a number and the lower the number, the higher the importance of the message.

The levels are useful in deciding what should be displayed to the user on the console and what should not be.

Every console has a log level called the console log level and any message with a log level number less than the console log level gets displayed on the console, and other messages which have a log level number higher or equal to the console log level are logged in the kernel log (kernel buffer) which can be looked into using the command [dmesg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg).

The console loglevel can be found by looking into the file */proc/sys/kernel/printk*:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

Output:

```
4 4 1 7
```

The first number in the output is the console log level, the second is the default log level, third is the minimum log level and the fourth is the maximum log level.

Log level 4 corresponds to KERN_WARNING. Thus all the messages with log levels 3, 2, 1, and 0 will get displayed on the screen as well as logged and the messages with log level 4, 5, 6, and 7 only get logged and can be viewed using *dmesg*.

The console log level can be changed by writing into the proc entry

```
echo "6" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

Output:

```
6 4 1 7
```

Now the console log level is set to 6, which is KERN_INFO.

Here you want to print out every message, so you should set your console level at the highest number, "8":

```
echo "8" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
tail -f /var/log/kern.log &
```

or

```
cat /proc/kmsg & (Android Environment)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
dmesg -wH &
```

to force all your kernel messages that are printed to dmesg (and also the virtual terminals, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, depending on your */proc/sys/kernel/printk* log level and a level of your message), to also appear at your SSH or GUI console: Konsole, Terminal or whatever you are using! And, if you need to monitor only for the specific messages:

```
dmesg -wH | grep ERR &
```

I'm using it to monitor for the "ERROR" messages like

```
printk(KERN_EMERG "ERROR!\n");
```

that I printk from my driver.

Answer (score 1):

[printk()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printk) is a function provided by the Linux kernel to print debug/information/error messages. Internally, the kernel maintains a circular buffer that is `__LOG_BUF_LEN` bytes long (depending on the configuration, it can range from 4KB to 1MB).

There are 8 possible loglevels associated to messages and defined in [linux/kernel.h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/kernel.h):

- `KERN_EMERG`: Emergency (system is unusable)
- `KERN_ALERT`: Serious problem (i.e. action must be taken immediately)
- `KERN_CRIT`: Critical condition, usually related to hardware or software failure
- `KERN_ERR`: Used for error conditions, usually related to hardware difficulties
- `KERN_WARNING`: Used to warn about problematic situations that are not serious
- `KERN_NOTICE`: Normal situations that require notification
- `KERN_INFO`: Informational messages; many drivers print information about the hardware found
- `KERN_DEBUG`: Used only for debugging

Each string represents a number ranging from 0 to 7, with smaller values representing higher priorities. The default log level is equal to the
`DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LOGLEVEL` variable specified in [kernel/printk/printk.c](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/printk/printk.c).

How messages can be read from user-level depends both on the configuration of some user-level daemons (e.g., [klogd](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4058) and [syslogd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog)) and on the default loglevel. To answer your question, depending on your specific configuration, one or more of the following commands will allow you to read the output of printk:

- The `dmesg` console command (usually, the preferred way for one-shot manual checking)
- The `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` command
- Through `/proc/kmsg` (discouraged)

Depending on your configuration, you may also want to change the default loglevel shown in console. Starting from klogd 2.1.31, the default loglevel can be changed by echoing into `/proc/sys/kernel/printk`. Examples:

- `echo 5 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` will display on console only messages with loglevel from 0 to 4
- `echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` will display on console messages with any loglevel