# How does the command 'echo "6" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk' work?

Tags: linux, shell, file, printing, linux-kernel

Please see an example in [How can I show printk() message in console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903915/how-can-i-show-printk-message-in-console),

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
4 4 1 7
$ echo "6" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
6 4 1 7
```

If the /proc/sys/kernel/prink was a normal file, the file would have changed to just "6", a single number. But I know the proc file system is a file system in ram and I guess it works different. In what mechanism did the file changed that way? And if I wanted to change the content to 4 6 1 7, can I do it with echo command and redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filesystem entries under `/proc` behave somewhat like function calls. "Writing" a string to the file is like calling a function with the string as an argument. "Reading" from the file is like calling a function with no argument and getting back the return value. The behavior of each "function" is defined by the kernel (or at least, by the `proc` file system exposed by the filesystem entries).

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-basics.html for the details on how `printk` in particular works. In short, writing a number to the file changes the current logging level, while reading shows the current (if changed), default, minimum, and boot-time default logging levels.

Comment: Thank you! I found this too. https://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x769.html. So I guess the shell program provides the 'driver' for reading and writing the proc files. Is it correct? (of course the files in proc fs are made by kernel)

Comment: No, it's the file system driver. The shell (ultimately) just uses `syswrite` to write to a file, regardless of what kind of filesystem entry it is. It's the file system driver `proc` that defines what it actually *means* to write to a file: write bytes to a disk file, make a system call, etc.